# Column Does Not Exist Even Though THe Procedure Is Not Executed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two separate procedures. One procedure alters the existing table with new columns. The other procedure adds data to the tables. They aren't being executed, only created. When I hit run, the procedure that adds data to the columns throws an error saying the column does not exist. I understand that it's not created because I didn't exec the procedure that contains the altered code. Not sure why the code inside the procedure executes since I thought that it only creates the procedure.

Some of the code is repetitive and I understand. This is simply to get a working solution before modifying it dynamically.

[image: Alter Table procedure]

[image]

Comment: Wasn't me but probably because you have pasted pictures of your code and errors, instead of the cutting and pasting it into your question.

Comment: To answer your question the proc is being compiled, and since the column doesn't exist, the compilation fails. I suspect if you did it in a single proc it would work because the compiler can work out that you are creating before you update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this more fully than my comment - Stored procedures are compiled. So if you try and do something that is invalid, the compilation will fail. It is not only checked at runtime.

Try this and it will fail every time:

```
create table junk(a int)

create procedure p as
update junk set b=1
```

Comment: It was great
A simple but effective solution
thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work, run the procedure that creates the columns before you attempt to create the procedure that inserts the data, or change the insert procedure so that it uses dynamic sql

Note that if you're desperate to have a db that has no columns but has a procedure that references them for insert, you can create the columns, create the insert procedure and then drop the columns again. The procedure won't run because dropping the columns invalidated it, but it will still exist

Not quite sure why you'd want to though- db schema is very much a design time thing so the design should be evolutionary. If you're doing this as part of a wider work in a front end language, take a look at a database migratory tool - it's a device that runs scripts, typically on app startup, that ensures the db has all the columns and data the app needs for that version to run. It's bidirectional too, typically, so if you downgrade then the migratory will/can remove columns and data it added